# How to map csv headers to sql field name in rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a csv file with headers `name, dept, class`. And the table in my sql database field has columns named `id, name, class, dept, block`.

How do I store and map these csv content into the sql database?

Comment: Do you simply want to load the data from a CSV file into a SQL table?

Comment: See my answer below. You should remove the ruby-on-rails tag here.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the order of columns in your CSV, then just remove the header and run the following command on the mysql prompt:

```
load data local infile 'uniq.csv' into table tblUniq fields terminated by ','
  enclosed by '"'
  lines terminated by '\n'
    (uniqName, uniqCity, uniqComments)
```

This will be much much faster than loading each row and creating an ActiveRecord object for each row.

For more information, check out the mysql documentation here for loading data: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html.

Answer (score 0):

For me I use [CSV-Mapper](http://csv-mapper.rubyforge.org/), It creates an array of hashes, and uses the first line (the headers) to create the key names in the hash, and each line is the value

Scroll down the page and check the example @ `Automagical Attribute Discovery Example` and `Import to ActiveRecord Example`